# Modify S3 object without returning it?

Tags: r, r-s3

I'm new to object-oriented programming in R and struggle with how to properly write a function that modifies an object.

This example works:

```
store1 <- list(
  apples=3,
  pears=4,
  fruits=7
)
class(store1) <- "fruitstore"
print.fruitstore <- function(x) {
  paste(x$apples, "apples and", x$pears, "pears", sep=" ")
}
print(store1)
addApples <- function(x, i) {
x$apples <- x$apples + i
x$fruits <- x$apples + x$pears
return(x)
}
store1 <- addApples(store1, 5)
print(store1)
```

But I suppose there should be a cleaner way to do this without returning the whole object:

```
addApples(store1, 5)  # Preferable line...
store1 <- addApples(store1, 5)  # ...instead of this line
```

What is the proper way to write modify-functions in R? "<<-"?

Update: Thank you all for what became a Rosetta Stone for OOP in R. Very informative.
The problem I'm trying to solve is very complex in terms of flow, so the rigidness of reference classes may bring the structure to help. I wish I could accept all responses as answers and not only one.

Comment: If you really want to modify in place, then perhaps you shouldn't be using S3 objects, but [reference class](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#rc) objects instead.

Comment: Good commment. The purpose of reference class suddenly make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reference class implementation, as suggested in one of the comments. The basic idea is to set up a reference class called `Stores` that has three fields: `apples`, `pears` and `fruits` (edited to be an accessor method). The `initialize` method is used to initialize a new store, the `addApples` method adds apples to the store, while the `show` method is equivalent to `print` for other objects.

```
Stores = setRefClass("Stores", 
  fields = list(
    apples = "numeric",
    pears  = "numeric",
    fruits = function(){apples + pears}
  ), 
  methods = list(
    initialize = function(apples, pears){
      apples <<- apples
      pears <<- pears
    },
    addApples = function(i){
      apples <<- apples + i
    },
    show = function(){
      cat(apples, "apples and", pears, "pears")
    }
  )
)
```

If we initialize a new store and call it, here is what we get

```
FruitStore = Stores$new(apples = 3, pears = 4)
FruitStore

# 3 apples and 4 pears
```

Now, invoking the `addApples` method, let us add 4 apples to the store

```
FruitStore$addApples(4)
FruitStore

# 7 apples and 4 pears
```

EDIT. As per Hadley's suggestion, I have updated my answer so that `fruits` is now an accessor method. It remains updated as we add more `apples` to the store. Thanks @hadley.

Comment: Seems like `fruits` shouldn't be a field, but a computed method (or if you wanted to be really fancy you could do an accessor method so `FruitStore$fruit` would still work)

Comment: True. I have updated my answer using accessor methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do this with S3 classes with replacement functions if you want to save yourself diving into reference classes.  First, your example

```
store1 <- list(apples=3,pears=4)
class(store1) <- "fruitstore"
print.fruitstore <- function(x) {
  x <- paste(unlist(store1), names(store1), collapse=", ")
  x <- paste0(x, " for a total of ", sum(unlist(store1)), " fruit.")
  NextMethod()
}
store1
# [1] "3 apples, 4 pears for a total of 7 fruit."
```

Notice how using `NextMethod` means I don't have to do `print(store1)`, I can just type `store`.  Basically, once I re-assign `x` to be what I want to show up on screen, I just dispatch the default `print` method.  Then:

```
`addapples<-` <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("addapples<-")
`addapples<-.fruitstore` <- function(x, value) {
  x[["apples"]] <- x[["apples"]] + value
  x
}
addapples(store1) <- 4
store1
# [1] "7 apples, 4 pears for a total of 11 fruit."
```

Tada! Again, not really the typical S3 usage case.  Except for the `[` and `[[` functions, replacement functions are typically intended to update attributes (e.g. class, length, etc.), but I don't see too much harm in stretching that.

Note this is not a real by reference assignment.  Really, your `fruitstore` object is copied, modified, and re-assigned to the original variable (see [R Docs](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment)).

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the [data.table package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).

Load the package: `library(data.table)`

Define a data.table object:

```
store1 <- data.table(apples=3,
                 pears=4,
                 fruits=7)
```

Then define the function addApple:

```
 addApple <- function(data,i) {data[,apples:=(data[1,apples]+i)]; 
                             data[,fruits:=(data[1,apples]+data[1,pears])]}
```

That's it.

When you write `addApple(store1)` you should get +i apples and "apples + pears" fruits.

And you can still define your S3 class if you want, just make sure that it inherits the data.frame and data.table classes.

```
class(store1) <- c("fruitstore",class(store1))
```

One more thing, you should rewrite your S3 method for print by making print explicit:

```
print.fruitstore <- function(x) {
   print(paste(x$apples, "apples and", x$pears, "pears", sep=" "))
}
```

Or you could just use cat:

```
print.fruitstore <- function(x) {cat(x$apples, "apples and", x$pears, "pears")}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation using the [proto package](http://r-proto.googlecode.com) which unifies objects and classes into  the single concept of prototypes.  For example, here there is really no difference between `Fruitstore` which is an object that plays the role of a class and `store1` which is an object that plays the role of a particular store.  They are both proto objects.

```
library(proto)

Fruitstore <- proto(
    addApples = function(., i) {
        .$apples <- .$apples + i
        .$fruits <- .$apples + .$pears
    },
    print = function(.) cat(.$apples, "apples and", .$pears, "pears\n")
)

# define store1 as a child of Fruitstore
store1 <- Fruitstore$proto(apples = 3, pears = 4, fruits = 7)

store1$addApples(5)
store1$print()
```