# R reference classes - how to extend a generator object?

Tags: r, class, oop, reference-class

I want to extend a generator object, but all the R help files have on this subject is:

> Note that if one wanted to extend the reference class generator
>   capability with a subclass, this should be done by subclassing
>   `refGeneratorSlot`, not `refObjectGenerator`.

OK, but how do you actually do this? So I've tried:

```
MyGenerator <- setRefClass("MyGenerator",
    contains = "refGeneratorSlot",
    methods = list(
        new = function(...) {
            message("Hello, I'm being instantiated now!")
            callSuper(...)
        }
    )
)
```

but now what? How do I actually use this in conjunction with my class definitions that use `setRefClass()`?

Comment: Since you have a lot of tough questions about reference classes, it might be wise to contact John Chambers.  He hangs out a lot on the r-devel mailing list, and is usually happy to answer questions via email (jmc at r-project dot org).

Comment: I think the answer to [this question][1] is what you want.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243359/modify-s3-object-without-returning-it/