# R: modifying property of an existing S3 object with a generic method

Tags: r, oop, r-s3

Let's say I have a constructor of a class with two properties with one initiated and the other set to `NULL`:

```
myclass <- function(data) {
  structure(
    list(data1 = data,
         data2 = NULL),
    class = "myclass")
}
```

And a generic:

```
myadd <- function(obj, x) {
  UseMethod("myadd")
}

myadd.myclass <- function(obj, x) {
  obj$data2 = obj$data1 + x
}
```

When I do:

```
mc = myclass(1)
myadd(mc, 2)
```

The property `data2` does not change:

```
> mc
$data1
[1] 1

$data2
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
```

Obviously, when I assign the result to a variable:

```
tmp = myadd(mc, 2)
```

I get the result:

```
> tmp
[1] 3
```

How to modify the property of an existing object with a generic function? Is it even kosher to do so?

I'm guessing I'm missing some crucial piece of info about S3 classes in R or about OOP in general. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: you need to return `obj` in `myadd.myclass`

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243359/modify-s3-object-without-returning-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) pass it back** R makes a copy of `obj` in the function when there is an attempt to modify it.  The original `obj` is not changed.  The idea is that R is a functional language and that minimizes side effects.

Pass it back to the caller and assign it in the caller.

```
myadd.myclass <- function(obj, x) {
  obj$data2 = obj$data1 + x
  obj
}

mc <- myclass(1)
mc <- myadd(mc, 2)
mc
## $data1
## [1] 1
##
## $data2
## [1] 3
##
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "myclass"
```

**2) replacement method** Another possibility is to define a replacement function:

```
"myadd<-" <- function(x, ..., value) UseMethod("myadd<-")
"myadd<-.myclass" <- function(x, ..., value) { x$data2 <- x$data1 + value; x }

mc <- myclass(1)
myadd(mc) <- 2
mc
## $data1
## [1] 1
##
## $data2
## [1] 3
##
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "myclass"
```

**3) environment** Yet another approach is to use an environment rather than a list.

```
myclass <- function(data) {
    structure(local({
      data1 = data
      data2 = NULL
      environment()
    }), class = c("myclass", "environment"))
}

# next two functions are same as in question
myadd <- function(obj, x) UseMethod("myadd")
myadd.myclass <- function(obj, x) obj$data2 = obj$data1 + x

obj <- myclass(1)
myadd(obj, 2)
as.list(obj)
## $data1
## [1] 1
##
## $data2
## [1] 3
```

Comment: This. "R is a functional language" should be emphasised

Comment: That’s very educational, thank you! Which of these options would be recommended from the performance/memory management point of view? In reality `data1` and `data2` would be potentially big `data.table`’s. Are S3 classes even appropriate for that? Should I opt for the S6 framework?

Comment: (1) is the most widely used  (2) is consistent with it -- it only changes the method discussed but the data is still stored the same way so it is optional.  I wouldn't try to guess on performance since that tends to result in surprises.  Implement any approaches you are considering and then benchmark them.